# Missing template exception_notifier/exception_notification.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, missing-template, exception-notification

The following error occurs when an exception is generated.  I am using vendor/rails-2.3.10 and ruby 1.8.7

> Missing template exception_notifier/exception_notification.erb in view path app/views

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the app is trying to load `app/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.html.erb` and can't find it.

The easy (and wrong) solution is to create that file, and maybe put some HTML in it, though possibly an empty file will do.

The correct solution is to look at the documentation for the exception_notifier plugin you appear to have installed, and figure out why it's looking for that view, and either put something relevant there (the plugin probably has an example) or disable rendering of that view when an exception occurs.